# Create Django model where the default value is not shown in my form

Tags: django, django-models

Im trying to create a Django model with a default value, something like this:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    image = models.URLField(max_length=200, default='https://example.com')
```

And a form for this model:

```
classExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ('image')
```

The thing is that by doing this when I display the form in an HTML template, the image field comes prepopulated with `https://example.com`, I want the filed to be empty and if the user doesn't input any value it takes the default one but that this is not shown in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default value in your model And check if the field is empty in form.is_valid function in your view.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/

Or you can keep the default value of your image and remove it in your form initiation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial